# jQuery bind with a different this

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to bind a function to an event but I want to change the context in which the function is called

```
function Foo(){

  t : "123",
  bar: function(){
    // I am here
    $('#selector').bind('click' this.foo);
  }
  ,
  foo: function(){
    //I want when to be able to use the current object here by this
    //this.t should be 123 and this.bar should call the above function
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/):

```
$('#selector').bind('click', $.proxy(this.foo,this) );
```

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for the clarification. +1, I thought jQuery will overwrite the Context when calling the function. Good Thing learned.

Comment: +1 for `$.proxy`. The alternate signature can be used as well, which is designed specifically for this scenario where the context object has its own reference to the method. `$.proxy(this, 'foo')`

Comment: Good point @amnotiam . However the signature you suggested I should not use, because it's more error prone, than signature I have posted. Consider the case,when method's name(`foo`) somehow will be changed. Then unless `click` event won't be triggered,you will not find an error (kind of `Object has no method 'foo'`).But by using '`$.proxy(function,context)`' signature, you will get an error,when `click` event will be binded.

Comment: @Engineer: Why do you think there would be a difference? The first thing jQuery does is [swap the parameters](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.7.2/src/core.js#L779-785) so you end up with the same thing as passing your original signature. If the function name changes, the function will end up as `undefined` in both cases.

Comment: @amnotiam Hmm..I have looked at sources, and you're right. So the both are error prone. No exceptions, when method does not exist.Hmm, strange solution by `jQuery` developers, which will cause to silent bugs.

Comment: Yeah, seems like jQuery doesn't offer much in terms of error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the reference to the object to a local variable, and use it in a function:

```
var me = this;
$('#selector').bind('click' function() { me.foo(); });
```

If you need the event object, pass that on:

```
var me = this;
$('#selector').bind('click' function(e) { me.foo(e); });
```

Comment: yes I know i can do this but I dont really like it. I am using backbone.js you can get a better Idea of why I don't want a copy if you look at this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066543/backbone-js-and-jquery-binding-click-event-to-a-view-function